# GeddyJs (NodeJs framework) deploying to heroku cedar stack crashes

Tags: node.js, heroku, geddy

I have a geddyJs app that is crashing when starting..

the crash log is:

```
2013-02-14T04:04:19+00:00 heroku[run.4236]: Starting process with command `geddy -e production`
2013-02-14T04:04:19+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2013-02-14T04:04:19+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:340
2013-02-14T04:04:19+00:00 app[web.1]:     throw err;
2013-02-14T04:04:19+00:00 app[web.1]:           ^
2013-02-14T04:04:19+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/config/true'
2013-02-14T04:04:19+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
2013-02-14T04:04:19+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
2013-02-14T04:04:19+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
2013-02-14T04:04:19+00:00 app[web.1]:     at require (module.js:378:17)
2013-02-14T04:04:19+00:00 app[web.1]:     at config.readConfig (/app/node_modules/geddy/lib/config.js:49:24)
2013-02-14T04:04:19+00:00 app[web.1]:     at _readConfig (/app/node_modules/geddy/lib/cluster/master.js:36:30)
2013-02-14T04:04:19+00:00 app[web.1]:     at async.AsyncBase.runItem (/app/node_modules/geddy/node_modules/utilities/lib/async.js:108:10)
2013-02-14T04:04:19+00:00 app[web.1]:     at async.AsyncBase.next (/app/node_modules/geddy/node_modules/utilities/lib/async.js:113:12)
2013-02-14T04:04:19+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Master.start (/app/node_modules/geddy/lib/cluster/master.js:257:11)
2013-02-14T04:04:19+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.utils.mixin.startCluster (/app/node_modules/geddy/lib/geddy.js:64:9)
2013-02-14T04:04:19+00:00 heroku[run.4236]: State changed from starting to up
2013-02-14T04:04:20+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-02-14T04:04:20+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

My Procfile is:

```
web: geddy -e $NODE_ENV
```

My Package.json file is:

```
{
        "name": "new-gorelative",
        "version": "0.0.1",
        "auther": "Mike DeVita <mike@gorelative.com>",
        "dependencies": {
            "geddy": "0.6.x",
            "handlebars": "*"
        },
      "engines": {
        "node": "0.8.x",
        "npm": "1.1.x"
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i figured it out.

Edit the `config/production.js` file and delete/comment the following lines(port, hostname)

```
var config = {
  //port: '3000',
  // hostname: '0.0.0.0'
};
```

Add a `app.js` javascript file to your app's root directory, the configs set in this will override production.js

```
var geddy = require('geddy');

geddy.startCluster({
  hostname: process.env.IP || '127.0.0.1',
  port: process.env.PORT || '3000',
  // you can manually set this to production, or set an environment variable via heroku..
  environment: 'production'
  // just uncomment the below line, and delete the above line.
  // you will need to set an environment variable in heroku by running
  // heroku config:set NODE_ENV=production
  //environment: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
});
```

Add a `Procfile` text file to your app's root directory

```
web: node app.js
```

remove the line for `config\secrets.json` in your `.gitignore` file - **note:** This is insecure, on public repo's as it exposes your cookie's secret hash.

Answer (score 1):

The deployment documentation has been updated to reflect the current steps needed to deploy to heroku (amongs others). New changes will/should be updated there.